# How can I establish origin/ authenticity of a electronic document

Tags: legal, pdf

**Scenario:** PartyA had put up an online offer on PartyB's certain product, if I bought the product through PartyA's channel then I shall be entitled to an specific gift/reward if PartyB approves my request and agrees to deliver the same.
PartyB has approved my request to purchase the product and provided written confirmation on the same.

**Issue:**

- The offer is old and now is not available and has been replaced by exactly similar offer with different name and  dates on their PartyA website. I have a PDF copy of PartyB's offer which list certain TnC.
- PartyA's scheme was feeling a little shady for me from the start and as a result I am not getting any response in return for several of my enquireirs about the so called "specific gift/reward".

I want to file a complain in consumer forum (a legal entity in India to deal with consumer related complains) with copy PartyB's offer. The challenge I might face here is to prove origin of that PDF. How can I do that?

Comment: The type of valid evidence will be up to the consumer forum. This is a question for them. One way is to use the Wayback Machine or cached Google results from that time to see what the site looked like at a point in time.

Comment: If it isn't digitally signed, this will be difficult.